# How can I overlay a frame with news on top of a already established website first page?

Tags: php, html

I'm having problems on finding a easy solution to present a news frame on top of the already established website first page.

The site should open with a news frame on top of the first page and close either by closing the frame or after a given time.

The site is developed with PHP and some JS for some specific functions and for what I could understand it uses some template which I can't identify.

I appreciate any help you can give me to point me in the right direction.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to put a frame (*what kind of frame? an `iframe`?...?*) on top of another frame that pops up on a site so that you can show news?

Comment: The goal is just to have an overlay frame appearing on top of the current website, as soon as I enter the website.I want a rectangle with some text in it to appear. After some given time or once the user closes this news window, the site should display as is right now.

Comment: Yes, Darren. Thank you. The site uses some modal tags to display this kind of frame once we click some menu items. But I don't know how to add this up to the first page of the website. The website is www.palankinha.apdes.pt, if it helps you.

Comment: The trick is to create the model with all the news, and then have a hidden `<a>` tag that you simply run some jquery to trigger when the page loads, showing the model - `jQuery('#button-id').trigger('click');`

Comment: Ok, I get the creation of the hidden modal, but I can't seem to grasp how to get it to show up once you enter the website. How can I use Jquery to trigger this modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is essentially to have a modal with all your news content in it. And you need a link to trigger that modal, so you need to create a hidden one. This is the general flow you should take to make it pop up the first time.

```
<a href="#" id="news-modal"></a>

<div class="modal"....>
    ......
</div>
```

Now to make it auto trigger, you'll need this little piece of jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a#news-model').trigger('click');
});
```

Note: If you only want it on the home page, only add it there!